# Evaluting triple integrals via change of variables

Tags: calculus

Use change of variables to evaluate the following integral

$$\int_{0}^1 \left(\int_{0}^{1} \left(\int_{x^2}^{1}  12xze^{zy^2}dy\right)dx\right)dz$$

What i did first was to first get rid of the $dx$ term by integrating wrt $x$

Hence getting $$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{x^2}^{1}  6ze^{zy^2}dydz$$

From here i attempted to perform the change of variables but i got stuck from here onwards. One problem is that even if i perform the change of variables, it does not seem to simplify the problem. Secondly is that the $x^2$ term still appears on the iterated integral which makes it difficult to perform the change of variables. Could anyone explain. Thanks

Comment: I would say you can not integrate first by the variable x!

Comment: I agree with georg because $x^2$ appeared as the boundary of the integration of $y$.

Comment: Obviously, I was in my first comment was wrong. See answer to user @ Julián Aguirre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track: integrate first in$x$. This changes the limits of integration:
$$
\int_0^1\int_?^?\int_?^? 12\,x\,z\,e^{zy^2}\,dxdydz
$$
I let it to you to find what the $?$ signs stand for.

Comment: So that means i can integrate first wrt $x$ and change the triple integral to a double integral?

Comment: Excellent advice, changing the order of integration and change the limits of integration all incredibly easier. And I thought it was inadmissible - perhaps I apologize my age.

Comment: No, it is still a triple integral, but calculations done like this suddenly become easy. Haven't you learned about changing the order of integrtation?

Comment: Oh thanks for ur hint. I managed to solve the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the integral

$$\int_{0}^1 \left(\int_{0}^{1} \left(\int_{x^2}^{1}  12xze^{zy^2}dy\right)dx\right)dz$$

We will integrate $z$ first:

$$I(x,y^2)=\int_{0}^{1}  12xze^{zy^2}dz=\frac{12x(1 + e^{y^2}(-1 + y^2))}{y^4}$$

Set $y^2=Y$ so that $dy=\frac{dY}{2\sqrt{Y}}$ and

$$\int_{0}^{1} \left(\int_{x^2}^{1}  I(x,y^2)dy\right)dx=\int_{0}^{1} \left(\int_{x}^{1}  \frac{I(x,Y)}{2\sqrt{Y}}dY\right)dx$$
$$=\int_{0}^{1} \left(\int_{0}^{Y}  \frac{I(x,Y)}{2\sqrt{Y}}dx\right)dY=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{3(1 + e^Y(-1 + Y))}{\sqrt{Y}}dY$$
$$=6 + e (3 - 9 F(1))=0.99098$$

Where F(z) is the [Dawson function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawson_function).

Comment: Wolfram dosent seem to give the same answer though

Comment: Well. Each step I used mathematica to calculate the result. Can you show the Mathematica commands that you used?